# Integrate Full cast and crew in a Movie Database

Tags: database-design

I'd like to display full cast and crew from my movie database and was wondering if the structure below is OK. Basically, I want something like this https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/284052-doctor-strange/cast

**[movies]**
id,
name

**[people]**
id,
name

**[jobs]**
id,
name (ex: Director, Writer)

**[casts]**
person_id,
movie_id,
character_name

**[crew]**
person_id,
movie_id,
job_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks good to me.

You have correctly defined 3 entities: Movies, Jobs, and People

You have correctly defined 2 associative entities: Cast & Crew

Your entities are independent of each other and the associative entities handle the many-to-many relationship...ie many People can work on many Movies.